# How do I sort the particular list of dictionary first on the basis of their Units (bit/s, Kbit/s, etc) and then sort them according to their value

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, prometheus

```
my_lst = [
        {"usage": "0.59 Kbit/s"},
        {"usage": "383.34 bit/s"},
        {"usage": "158.13 bit/s"},
        {"usage": "4.15 Gbit/s"},
        {"usage": "18.5 Mbit/s"},
        {"usage": "45 Kbit/s"}
    ]
```

The output trying to achieve should be something like this with sorted value:-

```
my_lst = [
    {'usage': '4.15 Gbit/s'}, 
    {'usage': '18.5 Mbit/s'}, 
    {'usage': '45 Kbit/s'}, 
    {'usage': '0.59 Kbit/s'}, 
    {'usage': '383.34 bit/s'}, 
    {'usage': '158.13 bit/s'}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oneway using [`humanfriendly.parse_size`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanfriendly):

```
from humanfriendly import parse_size

sorted(my_lst, key=lambda x: parse_size(x["usage"]), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[{'usage': '4.15 Gbit/s'},
 {'usage': '18.5 Mbit/s'},
 {'usage': '45 Kbit/s'},
 {'usage': '0.59 Kbit/s'},
 {'usage': '383.34 bit/s'},
 {'usage': '158.13 bit/s'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `humanfriendly` module:

```
from humanfriendly import parse_size
print(sorted(my_lst, key=lambda x: parse_size(x["usage"])[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers that uses the `humanfriendly` library is the better solution. Here is just an alternative without using a library.

```
from decimal import Decimal

UNIT_MAPPINGS = {
    "": 1,
    "K": pow(10, 3),
    "M": pow(10, 6),
    "G": pow(10, 9),
}

my_lst = [
    {"usage": "0.59 Kbit/s"},
    {"usage": "383.34 bit/s"},
    {"usage": "158.13 bit/s"},
    {"usage": "4.15 Gbit/s"},
    {"usage": "18.5 Mbit/s"},
    {"usage": "45 Kbit/s"}
]

def convert_rate(rate):
    num, _, unit = rate['usage'].partition(" ")
    unit = unit.replace('bit/s', '')
    return Decimal(num) * UNIT_MAPPINGS[unit]

my_lst.sort(key=convert_rate, reverse=True)
print(my_lst)
```

Output

```
[{'usage': '4.15 Gbit/s'}, {'usage': '18.5 Mbit/s'}, {'usage': '45 Kbit/s'}, {'usage': '0.59 Kbit/s'}, {'usage': '383.34 bit/s'}, {'usage': '158.13 bit/s'}]
```